# Can't turn my .py file in to a WORKING .exe file

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I've been struglying to convert my .py file in to a **working** .exe file. This is my first time doing it and I can't seem to find my mistake.

I've tryed two methods, **pyinstaller and cx_Freeze**, and both times the conversion would occur without any error, but when I try to open the .exe file, it blinks a CMD window and nothing happens.

**Can any one, please, help me?**

my program:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

verde='\033[1;32m'
vermelho='\033[1;31m'
preto='\033[0;30m'

'DATA FRAME FROTA'
Empilhadeiras={'Paletrans':['PR20','PR16'],'STILL':['FMX','EGU'], 'Ameise':['EJC','X']}
Modelos= pd.DataFrame(Empilhadeiras, columns=['Paletrans','STILL','Ameise'])
print(Modelos)
Custos={'Impostos':[]}
print()
print()

'VALOR DO MAQUINÁRIO'
num_maquinário = float(input("Digite o valor do maquinário: "))
str(float(num_maquinário))
print('R$'+str(float(num_maquinário)))
print()

'VALOR DOS IMPOSTOS'
num_txs = float(input("Digite a alíquota (sem %): "))
print(str(float(num_txs)) + '%')
txs=num_maquinário*(num_txs/100)
str(txs)
print('R$'+ str(txs))
print()

'DEPRECIAÇÃO DO MAQUINÁRIO'
num_depre = float(input("Digite o percentual de depreciação por ano (sem %): "))
print(str(float(num_depre)) + '%')
depre=num_maquinário*(num_depre/100)
str(depre)
print('R$'+ str(depre))
print()

'VALOR DO FRETE'
num_frete = float(input("Digite o valor do frete: "))
str(float(num_frete))
print('Frete trajeto único: R$'+ str(float(num_frete)))
num_frete*2
str(num_frete*2)
print('Frete ida e volta: R$' + str(num_frete*2))
print()

'DURAÇÃO DO CONTRATO'
num_dur = float(input("Digite o tempo de duração do contrato em meses( de 12 a 60): "))
str(float(num_dur))
print(str(float(num_dur))+' meses')
print()

'CUSTO COM SUBSTITUIÇÃO DE PEÇAS'
num_pec = float(input("Digite o custo médio para substituição de peças por mês: "))
str(float(num_pec))
print('R$'+str(float(num_pec)))
num_peças= num_pec*num_dur
print('Custo total com peças ao longo do contrato:R$'+str(num_peças))
print()


'NÚMERO DE VISITAS TÉCNICAS'
num_vis= float(input("Digite o número de visitas técnicas mensais planejadas: "))
str(float(num_vis))
print('R$'+str(float(num_vis)))
num_visit = num_vis*num_dur
print('Custo total com visitas ao longo do contrato: R$'+str(num_visit))
print()

'NÚMERO DE HORAS TÉCNICAS'
num_htec = float(input("Número médio de horas técnicas por atendimento: "))
if num_htec < 4:
    if num_htec < 4:
        print("R$100,00")
    elif 8> num_htec >4:
        print("R$200,00")
    elif 12> num_htec >8:
        print("R$300,00")
    else:
        print("R$500,00")
else:
    print("R$100,00") 
    
m = num_htec*num_vis    
def totTec(m):
    m = num_htec*num_vis    
    if m < 4:
        if m < 4:
            htec = 100
        elif 8> m>4:
            htec = 200
        elif 12> m>8:
            htec = 300
        elif 16> m>=12:
            htec = 500
        elif 20> m>16:
            htec = 750
        elif 24> m>20:
            htec = 1200
        else:
            htec = 1500
    else:
        htec = 250
    return htec    

print('Valor Tempo total: R$'+str(totTec(m)))
print()

'CUSTO DAS HORAS DE DESLOCAMENTO'    
num_dtemp = float(input("Tempo de deslocamento em horas até o cliente: "))
if num_dtemp < 4:
    if num_dtemp < 4:
        print("R$100,00")
    elif 8> num_dtemp >4:
        print("R$200,00")
    elif 12> num_dtemp >8:
        print("R$300,00")    
    else:
        print("R$400,00")
else:
    print("R$100,00")
str(num_dtemp*num_vis)    
print('Total de horas:'+str(num_dtemp*num_vis)) 

a=num_dtemp*num_vis
def totTemp(a):
    a=num_dtemp*num_vis
    if a < 4:
        if a < 4:
            temp= 100
        elif 8> a>4:
            temp= 200
        elif 12> a>8:
            temp= 300
        elif 16> a>12:
            temp= 400
        elif 20> a>16:
            temp= 500
        elif 24> a>20:
            temp= 600
        else:
            temp= 400
    else:
        temp= 100
    return temp
print('Valor Tempo total: R$'+str(totTemp(a))+',00')
print()

'CUSTO DA DISTÂNCIA DE DESLOCAMENTO ATÉ O CLIENTE'
num_distância = float(input("Digite a distância até o cliente em KM: "))
if num_distância*2 < 100:
    if num_distância*2 < 100:
        print("R$40,00")
    elif 250> num_distância*2 >100:
        print("R$100,00")
    elif 400> num_distância*2 >250:
        print("R$160,00")
    elif 550> num_distância*2 >400:
        print("R$220,00")
    elif 700> num_distância*2 >550:
        print("R$500,00")
    else:
        print("R$750,00")
else:
    print("R$50,00")

k = (num_distância*2)*num_vis
def distTot(k):
    k = (num_distância*2)*num_vis  
    if k < 100:
        if k < 100:
            dist = 40
        elif 250> k>100:
            dist = 160
        elif 400> k>250:
            dist = 220
        elif 550> k>400:
            dist = 280
        elif 700> k>550:
            dist = 340
        elif 1000>= k>850:
            dist = 400
        else:
            dist = 500
    else:
        dist = 40
    return dist


print('Valor Distância total: R$'+str(distTot(k))+',00')
print()

'CUSTO COM PEDÁGIO'
num_pedágio = float(input("Digite o gasto com pedágio: "))
str(float(num_pedágio))
print('Pedágios por visita: R$'+str(float(num_pedágio)))
num_tped = num_pedágio*num_vis
print('Gasto total com pedágio: R$'+str(num_tped))
print()

'CUSTO COM HOSPEDAGEM'
num_hospedagem = float(input("Digite o gasto com hospedagem: "))
str(float(num_hospedagem))
print('Hospedagem por visita: R$'+str(float(num_hospedagem)))
num_thost = num_hospedagem*num_vis
print('Gasto total com hospedagem: R$'+str(num_thost))
print()

'CUSTO COM ALIMENTAÇÃO'
num_alimentação = float(input("Digite o gasto com alimentação: "))
str(float(num_alimentação))
print('Gasto com alimentação por vista: R$'+str(float(num_alimentação)))
num_tal= num_alimentação*num_vis
print('Gasto total com alimentação: R$'+str(num_tal))
print()

'CUSTO TOTAL INICIAL'
cti= num_maquinário + txs + num_frete
print('Custo inicial: R$'+str(cti))
print()

'CUSTO TOTAL ANUAL'
cta= totTec(m) + num_pec + distTot(k) + totTemp(a) + num_tped + num_thost + num_tal 
print('Custo anual: R$'+str(cta))
print()

'CUSTO TOTAL'
CustoTotal= num_maquinário + txs + depre + + (num_frete*2) + totTec(m) + num_pec + distTot(k) + totTemp(a) + num_tped + num_thost + num_tal
print('Custo total: R$'+str(CustoTotal))
 
'VALOR DO ALUGUEL'
num_alg = float(input("Digite o valor da Parcela Aluguel: "))
str(float(num_alg))
print('R$'+str(float(num_alg)))
rend_anual= num_alg*12
print('Receita Anual:R$'+ str(rend_anual))
print()

'TAXA MÍNIMA DE ATRATIVIDADE'
num_tma = float(input("Digite a Taxa Mínima de Atratividade: "))
str(float(num_tma))
print(str(float(num_tma))+'%')
num_TMA=num_tma/100
print() 

dep1= num_maquinário - depre
dep2=dep1 - (dep1*num_depre)
dep3=dep2 - (dep2*num_depre)
dep4=dep3 - (dep3*num_depre)
dep5=dep4 - (dep4*num_depre)

ano_X=(rend_anual- cta)
ano_1=(rend_anual- cta + dep1 + num_frete)
ano_2=(rend_anual- cta + dep2 + num_frete)
ano_3=(rend_anual- cta + dep3 + num_frete)
ano_4=(rend_anual- cta + dep4 + num_frete)
ano_5=(rend_anual- cta + dep5 + num_frete)


n_1=12
n_2=24
n_3=36
n_4=48
n_5=60
Hipotese_1 = np.array([-cti,ano_1])
Hipotese_2 = np.array([-cti,ano_X,ano_2])
Hipotese_3 = np.array([-cti,ano_X,ano_X,ano_3])
Hipotese_4 = np.array([-cti,ano_X,ano_X,ano_X,ano_4])
Hipotese_5 = np.array([-cti,ano_X,ano_X,ano_X,ano_X,ano_5])

VPL_1=np.npv(rate=num_TMA, values=Hipotese_1)
VPL_2=np.npv(rate=num_TMA, values=Hipotese_2)
VPL_3=np.npv(rate=num_TMA, values=Hipotese_3)
VPL_4=np.npv(rate=num_TMA, values=Hipotese_4)
VPL_5=np.npv(rate=num_TMA, values=Hipotese_5)
print(VPL_1)
print(VPL_2)
print(VPL_3)
print(VPL_4)
print(VPL_5)

vpla_1=(VPL_1)*((num_TMA*(1+num_TMA)**n_1)/((1+num_TMA)**(n_1-1)))
vpla_2=(VPL_2)*((num_TMA*(1+num_TMA)**n_2)/((1+num_TMA)**(n_2-1)))
vpla_3=(VPL_3)*((num_TMA*(1+num_TMA)**n_3)/((1+num_TMA)**(n_3-1)))
vpla_4=(VPL_4)*((num_TMA*(1+num_TMA)**n_4)/((1+num_TMA)**(n_4-1)))
vpla_5=(VPL_5)*((num_TMA*(1+num_TMA)**n_5)/((1+num_TMA)**(n_5-1)))
print()
print('vpla_1 (12 meses)')
print(vpla_1)
if vpla_1>0: 
    print(verde+'Viável')
else:
    print(vermelho+'Inviável')
print(preto+'vpla_2 (24 meses)')
print(vpla_2)
if vpla_2>0: 
    print(verde+'Viável')
else:
    print(vermelho+'Inviável')
print(preto+'vpla_3 (36 meses)')
print(vpla_3)
if vpla_3>0: 
    print(verde+'Viável')
else:
    print(vermelho+'Inviável')
print(preto+'vpla_4 (48 meses)')
print(vpla_4)
if vpla_4>0: 
    print(verde+'Viável')
else:
    print(vermelho+'Inviável')
print(preto+'vpla_5 (60 meses)')
print(vpla_5)
if vpla_5>0: 
    print(verde+'Viável')
else:
    print(vermelho+'Inviável')
```

How I tried to convert it from cx:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='VPLA',
      version='0.1',
      description='Análise de viabilidade para aluguel de empilhadeiras 
      elétricas',
      executables= [Executable("VPLA.py")])
```

Then went to the Anaconda CMD  and typed:

```
python setup.py build
```

Comment: Show us your program and the command(s) you've used to make the exe and how each of them behave.

Comment: Hi, I added my program. It doesn't happen any error during the conversion but the .exe file don't open

Comment: Retracted my close vote and changed the downvote to an upvote :)